# Why does this if statement not recognise numbers?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, typeof

This code works fine on letters, returning if the letters are upper or lower case but it always returns the number as "6 is a uppercaseletter"

```
let userLetter = prompt("Please enter an uppercase, lowercase letter or a number");


if (typeof userLetter === 'number') {
    userLetter = userNumber;
    alert(`${userNumber} is a number`);
} else if (userLetter.toUpperCase() === userLetter) {
    alert(`${userLetter} is a uppercase letter`);
} else if (userLetter.toLowerCase() === userLetter) {
    alert(`${userLetter} is a lowercase letter`);
} else {
    alert('Something went wrong');
}
```

I expected the typeof operator would recognise that the input is a number but it doesn't. When a number is entered it always returns the uppercase option.

Comment: Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prompt` always returns a string (for which `typeof` returns `"string"`).

You could use `isNaN` instead.

```js
if (!isNaN(userLetter)) alert(`${userLetter} is a number`);
```